# PySpark: pull data to driver and then upload to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a pyspark dataframe from data stored in an external database. I use the `pyodbc` module to connect to the database and pull the required data, after which I use `spark.createDataFrame` to send my data to the cluster for analysis.

I run the script using `--deploy-mode client`, so the driver runs on the master node, but the executors can be distributed to other machines. The problem is `pyodbc` is not installed on any of the worker nodes (this is fine since I don't want them all querying the database anyway), so when I try to import this module in my scripts, I get an import error (unless all the executors happen to be on the master node).

My question is how can I specify that I want a certain portion of my code (in this case, importing `pyodbc` and querying the database) to run on the driver only? I am thinking something along the lines of

```
if __name__ == '__driver__':
  <do stuff>
else:
  <wait until stuff is done>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imports in your python driver **DO** only run on the master.  The only time you will see errors on your executors about missing imports is if you are referencing some object/function from one of those imports in a function you are calling on a driver.  I would look carefully at any python code you are running in `RDD`/`DataFrame` calls for unintended references.  If you post your code, we can give you more specific guidance.

Also, routing data through your driver is usually not a great idea because it will not scale well.  If you have lots of data you are going to try and force all through a single point which defeats the purpose of distributed processing!

Depending on what database you are using is, there is probably a Spark Connector implemented to load it directly into a dataframe.  If you are using ODBC then maybe you are using SQL Server?   For example, in that case you should be able to use JDBC drivers, like for example in this post:

https://stephanefrechette.com/connect-sql-server-using-apache-spark/#.Wy1S7WNKjmE

Answer (score 0):

This is not how spark is supposed to work. Spark collections (`RDD`s or `DataFrame`s) are inherently distributed. What you're describing is to create a dataset locally, by reading the **whole** dataset into drivers memory, and then sending it over to executors for further processing by creating an `RDD` or `DataFrame` out of it. That does not make much sense.

If you want to make sure that there is only one connection from spark to your database, then set the parallelism to 1. You can then increase the parallelism in further transformation steps.